# Is there any way to check if values are buffered in a Go chan?

Tags: go, buffer, channel, goroutine

How can I do something like the following?:

```
func foo(input <-chan char, output chan<- string) {
    var c char
    var ok bool
    for {
        if ThereAreValuesBufferedIn(input) {
            c, ok = <-input
        } else {
            output <- "update message"
            c, ok = <-input
        }
        DoSomethingWith(c, ok) 
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to check if there are buffered values in the chan so that if there aren't, I could send an update message before the thread is blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package main

func foo(input <-chan char, output chan<- string) {
        for {
                select {
                case c, ok := <-input:
                        if ok { // ThereAreValuesBufferedIn(input)
                                ... process c
                        } else { // input is closed
                                ... handle closed input
                        }
                default:
                        output <- "update message"
                        c, ok := <-input // will block
                        DoSomethingWith(c, ok)
                }

        }
}
```

EDIT: Fixed scoping bug.

Comment: I think this has a small bug in it, c and ok are out of scope by the time you hit DoSomethingWith, you have to pre-declare them outside the select with "var" and use "=" instead of := in the select statement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what the `select` call allows you to do.  It will enable you to check one or more channels for values ready to be read.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered your question for what you wanted to do with your code (use a `select`), but for completeness' sake, and to answer the specific question asked by your question's title ("Is there any way to check if values are buffered in a Go chan?"), the `len` and `cap` built-in functions work as expected on buffered channels (`len` returns the number of buffered elements, `cap` returns the maximum capacity of the channel).

http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity

Comment: Correct answer, just let me add than `len` of a channel is unavoidably racy, so it should not be relied upon as a deterministic value.

Comment: For people reading those comments, turns out `len` and `cap` on a channel are *not* racy. See http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements, and the discussion on golang-nuts (confirmed by Dmitry Vyukov): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/E467Ec0-bYQ/LVmbCodY1RAJ